# How to browse a channel letter by letter and compare with another channel and matching?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to create a script allowing me to compare a string of characters letter by letter (name) to another string of characters that will be a letter (Xchar).

Then, as long as it does not match, it continues to go through the condition until the last letter of the variable name.

Here is what I could do and I come to you for a script optimization:

```
name = "WALKER"
letterORregex = str(input("Enter a string. "))

splitCaracters = name.split()

for i in range(len(splitCaracters)):
  if splitCaracters[i] == letterORregex:
    print "send OK in list letterORregex"
  else:
    print "send down in list letterORregex"
```

Also I would like to add an exception when for example my variable (name) to a space: "john doe". I would like to be able to match my space character that is in my variable (name) with the character "_" in my variable (letterORregex). It's possible?

Comment: Your code doesn't work. `len(splitCaracters)` is always 1, so you only compare the first letter of name to your letter.

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you're trying to achieve. Try to rephrase your question so we can know what's your problem.

Comment: First I want to try to make a loop that allows me to compare each character of my string with another string
Let's take an example: 
string1 ="EXAMPLE"
string2 ="A"

If the first string string of string1 is not equal to string2 then the value changes to "B" ...etc until when it matches on the letter "E".

Then the loop goes to the "X" from string 1 and the condition repeats itself...etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say 'OK' is True and 'down' is False. Then you can do something like:

```
  string = "SomeString"
  variable = "SomeVariable"

  myList = [string[i]==variable[i] for i in range(min(len(string),len(variable)))]

  print(myList)
```

And then you'll have a wanted list(assuming I understand what you want)

Comment: Yes it is, can you explain more? Without function please?

Comment: That is called list comprehension(you can find out more by Googling it). Edited without function.

Comment: Yes it is, and how can I tell if in my list the value is True, I display "ok" and otherwise I display "ko" please?

Comment: for i in myList:
 if i:
  print(i)

Comment: I misspoke.

In my myList variable, I'd like to make a condition that says if the result is True then print "ok" and if the result is False then print "ko"

Comment: Oh, sorry.
for i in myList: print("ok" if i else "ko")